# Android Class Interface Expected

Tags: java, android

Here is my code, I cannot for the life of me figure it out why it keeps getting a class, interface enum expected and I for the life of me cannot figure out why.  At first I thought I had } misplaced but I cannot find out where that might be.  This is taken directly from a college text book, as we are required to use the code and recreate it and run it but to me it looks like older code meant for an earlier version of android studio.  I am sure I am over looking the obvious here but any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.chigh.tipcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Seekbar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat =
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
private static final NumberFormat percentFormat =
        NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

private double billAmount = 0.0;
private double percent = 0.15;
private TextView amountTextView;
private TextView percentTextView;
private TextView tipTextView;
private TextView totalTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

amountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amountTextView);
percentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentTextView);
tipTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipTextView);
totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTextView);
tipTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(0));
totalTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(0));
EditText amountEditText =
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);
amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(amountEditTextWatcher);

SeekBar percentSeekBar =
(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.percentSeekBar);
percentSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(percentSeekBarListener);
}

private void calculate() {
percentTextView.setText(percentFormat.format(percent));

double tip = billAmount * percent;
double total = billAmount + tip;

tipTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(tip));
totalTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(total));

final SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener =
new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean 
fromUser) {
percent = progress / 100.0;
calculate();

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}


};
final TextWatcher amountEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int 
after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{

try {
billAmount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) / 100.0;
amountTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(billAmount));
} 

catch (NumberFormatException e) {
amountTextView.setText("");
billAmount = 0.0;

}

calculate();
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
};

}

}
}
```

Comment: `private void calculate() {` is it closed properly?

Comment: I think you have to add a `}` after `totalTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(total));` and remove the last `}` from activity.

Answer (score 0):

1. delete one `}` at the bottom of your activity
2. add `import android.app.Activity;`
3. mark this answer as solved

Answer (score 0):

Make some change in your code like activity instand of AppComActivity and also remove one curler brace.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat =
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
private static final NumberFormat percentFormat =
        NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

private double billAmount = 0.0;
private double percent = 0.15;
private TextView amountTextView;
private TextView percentTextView;
private TextView tipTextView;
private TextView totalTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    amountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amountTextView);
    percentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentTextView);
    tipTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipTextView);
    totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTextView);
    tipTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(0));
    totalTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(0));
    EditText amountEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);
    amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(amountEditTextWatcher);

    SeekBar percentSeekBar =
            (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.percentSeekBar);
    percentSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(percentSeekBarListener);
}

private void calculate() {
    percentTextView.setText(percentFormat.format(percent));

    double tip = billAmount * percent;
    double total = billAmount + tip;

    tipTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(tip));
    totalTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(total));

    final SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener =
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean
                        fromUser) {
                    percent = progress / 100.0;
                    calculate();

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }


            };
    final TextWatcher amountEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int
                after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {

            try {
                billAmount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) / 100.0;
                amountTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(billAmount));
            }

            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                amountTextView.setText("");
                billAmount = 0.0;

            }

            calculate();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

}

}
```

and i hope you define your activity into android manifest file.